# SQL Server function ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY not calc

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have problem with the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ....)` function.

This is my original table which I work with:

```
PRODUCT    VERSION   Colour
------------------------------
Apple        7.1      Black
Apple        7.1      Blue
Apple        7.1      Red
Apple        2.0      NULL
Beer         12.8     Blue 
Beer         12.8     NULL
Beer         12.8     NULL
Bread        14.87    Blue  
Bread        14.87    NULL
Bread        14.87    Orange  
Notes        100      Red 
Notes        100      NULL
Car          NULL     Green
Car          NULL     Blue
Car          NULL     Red
Car          NULL     Red
```

I run this script against this table:

```
SELECT 
    [product], [version], [colour],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [product], [Version] ORDER BY [product] DESC) AS COUNT2  
FROM 
    TABLE1
```

Then I get an output like this:

```
PRODUCT    VERSION   Colour  COUNT2
-----------------------------------
Apple        7.1      Black   1
Apple        7.1      Blue    2
Apple        7.1      Red     3
Apple        2.0      NULL    4
Beer         12.8     Blue    1
Beer         12.8     NULL    2
Beer         12.8     NULL    3
Bread        14.87    Blue    1
Bread        14.87    NULL    2
Bread        14.87    Orange  3
Notes        100      Red     1   
Notes        100      NULL    2
Car          NULL     Green   1
Car          NULL     Blue    2
Car          NULL     Red     3
Car          NULL     Red     4
```

Then I select rows with maximal values

```
SELECT 
    [Product], [Version], MAX(COUNT2)
FROM 
    [dbo].[TABLE1] 
GROUP BY 
    Product, Version
```

But here I have problem. I can not get same numbers when I run function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` depend only on 1 column

I can not calculate back and get correct result if I calculate back way.

```
PRODUCT   VERSION    COUNT2
----------------------------
Apple       7.1       6
Apple       2.0       7
Beer        12.8      5
Bread       14.87     1 
Notes       100       6
Car         NULL      8
```

If I run script without version on the end I am getting different numbers when I do calculation back way

```
SELECT 
    [product], [version], [colour],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [product], ORDER BY [product] DESC) AS COUNT2  
FROM 
    TABLE1

SELECT 
    [Product], MAX(COUNT2)
FROM 
    [dbo].[TABLE1] 
GROUP BY 
    Product
```

Result is different than what I am expecting:

```
PRODUCT    COUNT
----------------
Apple        4
Beer         3
Bread        3
Notes        2
Car          4
```

I expected a result like this :

```
PRODUCT   VERSION    COUNT2
----------------------------
Apple       7.1       3
Apple       2.0       1
Beer        12.8      3
Bread       14.87     3 
Notes       100       2
Car         NULL      4
```

Thanks for help me to setup function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY....)`

Original table has over 10000 rows..

Comment: Why don't you want to use `COUNT`? First query will give you different result than you wrote...

Comment: @luka can you please check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    [product], [version], COUNT(*)  
FROM 
    TABLE1
GROUP BY [product], [version]
```

and tell me if it gives you what you want

P.S. You definitely have a problem with copy/paste: this code works fine:[image]

Comment: Ok but can you wait script run 20 min. and i need to join two table over them run this.

Comment: Please precise what you want as the result, just the last table from your post (PRODUCT   VERSION    COUNT2) that shows only the count or you need to ENUMERATE the rows of original table?

Comment: Oh I see.. I have more Columns like olnly colours.. I tried combinate them.. combination not working.. I think about function COUNT.as Rokuto

Comment: sepupic-ENUMERATE i do in head not sql..I need calculation

Comment: If you need only counts all that you need is GROUP BY, not row_number. Group By gives you less rows then your original table has, row_number gives you exact same rows + enumerates them

Comment: sepupic- GROUP BY what?

Comment: sepupic -COUNT(*)  its problem with * star.

Comment: sepupic- I can not run it

Comment: Do COUNT(1) if you don't like COUNT(*)

Comment: sepupic-Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: Post this error message as the picture, please, editing your question. With the code you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add count()along with partition  for your query

```
Select  PRODUCT,[VERSION], COUNT2 from  (
Select DISTINCT 
        PRODUCT, 
        VERSION,
        Count(COUNT2)OVER(PARTITION BY version )COUNT2 from (
SELECT 
    [product], 
    [version], 
    [colour],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [product], [Version] ORDER BY [product] DESC) AS COUNT2  
FROM 
    @Table1 )T
    GROup BY  PRODUCT, VERSION,COUNT2 )TT


    ORDER BY CASE WHEN VERSION IS NOT NULL then 0 else 1 END
```

Comment: mohan111 -what is : ;with CTE 
    AS (

Comment: Common table expression to get perfect order as your output I have used that

Comment: I have removed CTE and done in derived table itself @Luka